# Using DI but getting : An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker but

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inversion-of-control

None of the questions I have reviewed on this subject are using IOC whereas I am so I don't understand why I am getting this error. As I understand it, if I only have one instance of my context, I shouldn't be receiving this error. This is a broken down version of my setup.

I am trying to run this:

```
var product = new Product();
product.ShortText = "something";
foreach (var category in _categoryService.Get().Take(5).ToList())
    product.Categories.Add(category);
_productService.Update(product);
_productService.SaveChanges();
```

My `_productService`:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IRepository<Product> productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    //Code removed for brevity
}
```

`_categoryService` is pretty much the same as `_productService`.

`IRepository` is like this:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;

    public EfRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected virtual IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get { return _entities ?? (_entities = _context.Set<T>()); }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return Entities; }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        Entities.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id, entity);
    }
}
```

I am registering my context per request like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<CcDataContext>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Bearing this in mind, the way I see it, `_productService` and `_categoryService` should have the same instance of the context so I am confused as to why I get the error.

**Edit**

This is my context:

```
public class CcDataContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    static CcDataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CcDataContext>(null);
    }

    public CcDataContext()
        : base("CcDataContext") //String.Format("Name={0}", CcConfig.Get("ConnectionStringName")))
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Website> Websites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreView> StoreViews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerContact> CustomerContacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerRole> CustomerRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RolePermission> PermissionRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    public IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason for this. It was down the the caching I am performing on the `_categoryService`. My `Get()` method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Get()
{
    return _cacheManager.Get(CcCacheCategoryAll, () => (_categoryRepository.Table.AsEnumerable()));
}
```

Basically, because I am not detaching my entities from the context they were in when they were cached, I  then get the cached versions in a later request and they don't have the same context. So although it's not the DI at fault, it is because the context doesn't match between the entities.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with your DI container. That error means that somewhere in your context, you have created two `DbSet` properties that both point to the same entity.

Since the advent of ASP.NET Identity, the most common cause of this is individuals trying to add their own `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` property, when `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` already has one, which your application's context inherits.

Not sure if that's your problem, because you haven't specified what version of MVC you're using or posted the contents of your context. That should give you enough to look into the issue, though.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I was focusing on the wrong thing in that case. I'll jump in and take a look what's going on. p.s I'm using MVC5.

Comment: I've updated my OP with my context class. I don't use `IdentityDbContext` as I am using custom authentication not ASP.NET Identity. Based on your answer, I've looked for occurrences where I might be declaring multiple `DBSet<Something>` but can't find any.